# If/elseif statements not working

Tags: javascript, html

For a reason I can't Identify, this isn't being successfully called, I've tried everything I can think of, but nothing seems to get this to work, it has no errors.

```
<img id="risk" src="assets/R0.png" width="100" height="150" style="border: dotted;"><br>
<button id="ContinueBtn" onclick="Continue()">Continue</button>

if (document.getElementById("risk").src == "assets/R0.png"){    
    document.getElementById("risk").src = "assets/R1.png";
}
else if (document.getElementById("risk").src == "assets/R1.png"){
    document.getElementById("risk").src = "assets/R2.png";
}
else if (document.getElementById("risk").src == "assets/R2.png"){
    document.getElementById("risk").src = "assets/RF.png";
    document.getElementById("happiness").src = "assets/PF.png";
    document.getElementById("main").src = "assets/fired.png";
    alert("Debug")

    var Cont = document.getElementById("ContinueBtn");
    Cont.parentNode.removeChild(Cont);
}
```

When I add an else statement to it, it by passes the if and elseif's, making it seem like it is not finding anything for "risk",

```
else{
    alert("An error has occured! Try refreshing your page.")
}
```

Comment: Where is that code called from? Please show the related html. If the `src` starts as `...R0.png` wouldn't the first if change it, then the second if change it again, then the third if change it a third time (all in a row)? Should they be `else if` statements?

Comment: Why are you setting a value and then testing for the same value in the next line?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot that was my debug to test which if statement was breaking, though it was inconclusive.

Comment: Add a `console.log(document.getElementById("risk").src)` just before the first `if`, to confirm what value it actually has.

Comment: Please show us the HTML code and explain us what you are trying to test ^^

Comment: You are missing the `else` condition, put it there and you will see what's happening.

Comment: You sure like to type `document.getElementById("risk").src` a lot. Me I'd use a variable.

Comment: I did it for a reason, and If I must change it, there is something such as ctrl+f replace all.

Comment: @AleveWinter Readability isn't the only reason to use variables. Variables will prevent JS from re-computing the same thing many times in a row. I strongly suggest that you reconsider this. Personnaly, I even go as far as defining a one-liner function `_e` that returns `document.getElementById`. Believe me, sooner or later you WILL mistype this and then everything's broken.

Comment: And then you go into console and look at what line it's on and correct it? This is about if's and else if's, not about variables, it works fine in other parts of the code.

Comment: JavaScript do handle if and else if correctly. Your code is the problem.

Comment: Wasn't aware that I said JS was the problem, thanks for notifying me.

Comment: Sir, you don't help your cause. Please remember that we try to help, so quit showing us your ego and programming skills, then show the value of `document.getElementById("risk").src`.

Comment: I did show you the value, try refreshing your screen instead of camping the comments, good day sir.

Comment: *"And then you go into console and look at what line it's on and correct it?"* - Ah, so you *do* know how to use the console? Why didn't you do that to check the value of your variables before posting your question? Would've saved me writing out a long answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using RegExp:

```
var risk = document.getElementById("risk");
if (risk.src.match("assets/R0.png")){    
    risk.src = "assets/R1.png";
} else if(condition) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

When you test the `.src` property in JS, some browsers report the *full* path of the image even when your original markup only specified a relative path. Which means your `==` comparison will fail.

**Long answer:**

Assuming that block of code *is* called *after* the elements have been created, I think you'll find that the problem is that the `src` you set in your html is not the same as what is reported when you test the `.src` property. If your source code sets a relative path for the `src` you may find the `.src` property value reported by the browser is actually the *full* path. So, e.g.:

```
<img src="assets/R0.png">
```

...and then:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("risk").src);
```

...will log `"http://www.yourdomainhere.com/fullpath/assets/R0.png"`

Which of course won't be equal when you compare with `==`. Obviously you can easily test this by adding a `console.log()` statement just before the first if (or use an `alert()` if you must). **Whenever you find an `if` statement isn't doing what you expect the first thing to try is adding a `console.log()` of the variables involved in the expression so that you can be *sure* they have the values you think they do.**

If that *is* what's happening, then you obviously just need to use string functions to extract the last path of the path. E.g.:

```
var imgEl = document.getElementById("risk"),
    imgSrc = imgEl.src.split("/").pop();

if (imgSrc == "R0.png"){    
    imgEl.src = "assets/R1.png";
} else if (imgSrc == "R1.png") {
    imgEl.src = "assets/R2.png";
}
// etc.
```

The code `imgEl.src.split("/").pop()` that I've used takes the full path and uses `.split()` to create an array with all of the pieces between the forward slashes and then `.pop()` to take the last "piece", i.e. the last array element.

(I've also introduced a variable `imgEl` to reference your img element, because that's much neater and more efficient than repeatedly calling `document.getElementById()` for the same element.

Comment: I think there is no real question yet, the OP is missing information for an answer to be related. Althought it should help resolve its issue, I do hope that his question will improve so that it can be helpful to others.

Comment: @Frederik.L - Well, I took my best guess at what is most likely the problem. OP said there were no errors, so I take that to mean the code *runs* but none of the if conditions match. The `.src` issue I talk about explains why. (But yes, I could be wrong if there is some really important thing the OP hasn't mentioned.)

Comment: Agreed with the answer, just pointing out that "if / elseif not working" may not be used to find this answer. Hence, it may hurt answer's helpfulness until the OP gives more details.